# Is there any way to create a user defined signal in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, signals

Is there any way to create a user defined signals in Linux? My signal (signal number) should not match any of the existing signal numbers.

In other words, i want to create my own unique signal, which will be registered and caught by my handler.

Is it possible? If yes, how?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't add or register your own SIGWHATEVER.

See `sigset_t`, it is fixed size. See `valid_signal()` beartraps.

Comment: Where do u get this `valid_signal( )`? I could not find any man page for that.

Comment: @kingsmasher1: `valid_signal()` is a function in the Linux kernel that returns true if the signal is < the number of signals.  It's used by things like the `kill()` syscall to stop you from doing things like defining your own signals.

Answer (score 18):

`SIGRTMIN` through `SIGRTMAX` (these are not normally constants but macros which expand to functions evaluated at runtime) are available for whatever use you like, as are `SIGUSR1` and `SIGUSR2`. The former have additional realtime queueing support; the latter don't. Simply choose one to use.

Answer (score 7):

You can compile your own kernel with special signals :)

Answer (score 4):

There are the `USR1` and `USR2` signals designed for user defined purposes.

Comment: But that is a pre-defined. The signal number won't be unique, right?

Answer (score 3):

You can use USR1 and USR2 for this kind of thing.

If that's not enough, you can emulate signal like behaviour by having your application listen on a socket which external apps can send messages to.

Comment: But in that case, we can't register it with a signal handler. Can we? Because i want that when this signal to be used by a timer, and this signal no should be unique, not to clash with any existing signal. So the socket method is not feasible.

Comment: If its completely inside your program, you needn't use a signal. You can implement a simple messaging system and use that. Signals are best used for async communication between processes.

Comment: Noufal, that can't be used by a POSIX timer, timer_create.

Comment: I know. You'll have to implement something yourself.