# ualarm() equivalent (Android Bionic libc)

Tags: android, linux, android-ndk, libc, bionic

[ualarm()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/ualarm) is not implemented in Android version of libc, bionic (check [Bionic unistd.h](https://github.com/android/platform_bionic/blob/master/libc/include/unistd.h)). Moreover, ualarm() is obsolete.

I am porting an application on Android NDK so I need an equivalent of **ualarm(999999,999999)**, i.e. something that would send a **SIGALRM periodically** (every second).

Maybe with [timer_create()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/timer_create) ? It seems to be [implemented in Bionic](https://github.com/android/platform_bionic/blob/master/libc/include/time.h). But the example in the man page is really not trivial...

Code i'm willign to port to Android (NDK):

```
/* 
 * Set a recurring 1 second timer that will call sigalrm() and switch to 
 * a new channel.
 */

    act.sa_handler = sigalrm_handler;
    sigaction (SIGALRM, &act, 0);
    ualarm(CHANNEL_INTERVAL, CHANNEL_INTERVAL);
    change_channel(1);

/* Whenever a SIGALRM is thrown, go to the next 802.11 channel */
void sigalrm_handler(int x)
{
    next_channel();
}
```

Comment: The answer is in the Linux ualarm() man page: `This function is obsolete.  Use setitimer(2) or POSIX interval timers (timer_create(2), etc.) instead.`

Comment: Thanks but that's why I thought in the question. I've just spent 1 hour to get things done with the relevant code. And 1 more hour to create the delete timer code as ualarm(0, 0) equivalent requires a timer reference... (will update the answer for that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, create_timer was the key. Too bad nobody answered with an example in time.

I've built this code by simplifying [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5741871/2227298).

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <time.h>

// Handler that will be called every its.it_value.tv_sec seconds + its.it_value.tv_nsec nanoseconds until you kill the timer
static void handler(int sig, siginfo_t *si, void *uc)
{
        printf("Caught signal %d from timer\n", sig);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct sigevent sev;
    struct itimerspec its;
    sigset_t mask;
    struct sigaction sa;
    timer_t timerid;

    // Define sigaction: handler
    sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    sa.sa_sigaction = handler;
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sigaction(SIGUSR1, &sa, NULL);

    // Define sigevent
    sev.sigev_notify = SIGEV_SIGNAL;
    sev.sigev_signo = SIGUSR1;

    // Create the timer
    timer_create(CLOCK_REALTIME, &sev, &timerid);
    its.it_value.tv_sec = 1;
    its.it_value.tv_nsec = 0;
    its.it_interval.tv_sec = its.it_value.tv_sec;
    its.it_interval.tv_nsec = its.it_value.tv_nsec;
    timer_settime(timerid, 0, &its, NULL);

    // Sleeps (100sec) is aborted: its default behavior is to wake up when a signal is received (1sec)
    // So we sleep again to properly see the next signal in this example.
    // That's just for the example so that the process doesn't terminate.
    sleep(100); sleep(100); sleep(100); sleep(100); sleep(100); sleep(100);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Disabling a periodic timer was done with ualarm(0, 0). There was no need to pass a timer in argument. But with time_delete, we need this timer reference. So code must be adapted to remember the timer reference to disable it.

So to pass the timer by reference if needed:

```
some_function(..., &timerid);
void some_function(..., timer_t *timerid)
```

And to disable the timer:

```
timer_delete(timerid);
```

Also note that ualarm uses SIGALRM  signal. In this code we're using SIGUSR1 instead.

> SIGALRM, SIGVTALRM and SIGPROF
>       The SIGALRM, SIGVTALRM and SIGPROF signal is sent to a process when the time limit specified in a call to a preceding alarm setting
>   function (such as setitimer) elapses. SIGALRM is sent when real or
>   clock time elapses. SIGVTALRM is sent when CPU time used by the
>   process elapses. SIGPROF is sent when CPU time used by the process and
>   by the system on behalf of the process elapses.
>
> SIGUSR1 and SIGUSR2
>       The SIGUSR1 and SIGUSR2 signals are sent to a process to indicate user-defined conditions.

There might be timer conflicts if you're using several timers that all uses SIGUSR1. Check the [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5741871/2227298) to handle several timers all using SIGUSR1.