# Do I have to use a signal handler for a Posix timer?

Tags: c, timer, posix, sigaction

I want to start a timer and have a function called when it expires.

Googling finds lots of examples, including the example in the manual, all of which use `sigaction()` to set a signal handler.

However, @Patryk says in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5740954/problem-in-timers-and-signal) that we can just

```
void cbf(union sigval);
struct sigevent sev;
timer_t timer;

sev.sigev_notify = SIGEV_THREAD;
sev.sigev_notify_function = cbf; //this function will be called when timer expires
sev.sigev_value.sival_ptr = (void*) arg;//this argument will be passed to cbf
timer_create(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &sev, &timer);
```

which is shorter, simpler, cleaner, more maintainable ...

What gives? Is this correct? Is it just a wrapper for `sigaction()`? Why do the examples explicitly set a signal handler?

Also, if I start a timer either by this method, or by `timer_settime` and a signal handler, will cancelling the timer casue the system to remove the association between that timer and the callback, or do I have to do that explicitly?

---

[Update]  You can choose ***either*** signals or the method I show in my answer below (or both, but that seems silly). It is a matter of taste. Singals might offer a little more functionality, at the cost of complification.

If all you want to do is start a timer and be notified when it expires, the method in my answer is simplest.

Comment: I think the decision of choosing between threads or signals as the underlying notification interface for POSIX timers is entirely related to (opinion-based) whether you're willing to use threads (for whatever reason) on your application, or even if you don't, you're forced to use the thread notification system due to the signals interface not being an option for some reason (whatever that reason is... one good reason may be for the sake of simplicity).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It *seems* that I do not have to use a signal handler and can make the code much simpler, as shown here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static unsigned int pass_value_by_pointer = 42;

void Timer_has_expired(union sigval timer_data)
{
    printf("Timer expiration handler function; %d\n", *(int *) timer_data.sival_ptr);
}

int main(void)
{
    struct sigevent timer_signal_event;
    timer_t timer;

    struct itimerspec timer_period;

    printf("Create timer\n");
    timer_signal_event.sigev_notify = SIGEV_THREAD;
    timer_signal_event.sigev_notify_function = Timer_has_expired;       // This function will be called when timer expires
    // Note that the following is a union. Assign one or the other (preferably by pointer)
    //timer_signal_event.sigev_value.sival_int = 38;                        // This argument will be passed to the function
    timer_signal_event.sigev_value.sival_ptr = (void *) &pass_value_by_pointer;     // as will this (both in a structure)
    timer_signal_event.sigev_notify_attributes = NULL;
    timer_create(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &timer_signal_event, &timer);

    printf("Start timer\n");
    timer_period.it_value.tv_sec = 1;                                   // 1 second timer
    timer_period.it_value.tv_nsec = 0;                                  // no nano-seconds
    timer_period.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;                                // non-repeating timer
    timer_period.it_interval.tv_nsec = 0;

    timer_settime(timer, 0, &timer_period, NULL);
    sleep(2);

    printf("----------------------------\n");
    printf("Start timer a second time\n");
    timer_settime(timer, 0, &timer_period, NULL);
    sleep(2);

    printf("----------------------------\n");
    printf("Start timer a third time\n");
    timer_settime(timer, 0, &timer_period, NULL);

    printf("Cancel timer\n");
    timer_delete(timer);
    sleep(2);
    printf("The timer expiration handler function should not have been called\n");

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

when run, it gives this output:

```
Create timer
Start timer
Timer expiration handler function; 42
----------------------------
Start timer a second time
Timer expiration handler function; 42
----------------------------
Start timer a third time
Cancel timer
The timer expiration handler function should not have been called
```

Answer (score 4):

Michael Kerrisk has a detailed example in his "The Linux Programming Interface" book:

```
/* ptmr_sigev_thread.c

   This program demonstrates the use of threads as the notification mechanism
   for expirations of a POSIX timer. Each of the program's command-line
   arguments specifies the initial value and interval for a POSIX timer. The
   format of these arguments is defined by the function itimerspecFromStr().

   The program creates and arms one timer for each command-line argument.
   The timer notification method is specified as SIGEV_THREAD, causing the
   timer notifications to be delivered via a thread that invokes threadFunc()
   as its start function. The threadFunc() function displays information
   about the timer expiration, increments a global counter of timer expirations,
   and signals a condition variable to indicate that the counter has changed.
   In the main thread, a loop waits on the condition variable, and each time
   the condition variable is signaled, the main thread prints the value of the
   global variable that counts timer expirations.

   Kernel support for Linux timers is provided since Linux 2.6. On older
   systems, an incomplete user-space implementation of POSIX timers
   was provided in glibc.
*/
#include <signal.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include "curr_time.h"              /* Declares currTime() */
#include "tlpi_hdr.h"
#include "itimerspec_from_str.h"    /* Declares itimerspecFromStr() */

static pthread_mutex_t mtx = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
static pthread_cond_t cond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

static int expireCnt = 0;           /* Number of expirations of all timers */
static void                         /* Thread notification function */
threadFunc(union sigval sv)
{
    timer_t *tidptr;
    int s;

    tidptr = sv.sival_ptr;

    printf("[%s] Thread notify\n", currTime("%T"));
    printf("    timer ID=%ld\n", (long) *tidptr);
    printf("    timer_getoverrun()=%d\n", timer_getoverrun(*tidptr));

    /* Increment counter variable shared with main thread and signal
       condition variable to notify main thread of the change. */

    s = pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);
    if (s != 0)
        errExitEN(s, "pthread_mutex_lock");

    expireCnt += 1 + timer_getoverrun(*tidptr);

    s = pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);
    if (s != 0)
        errExitEN(s, "pthread_mutex_unlock");

    s = pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
    if (s != 0)
        errExitEN(s, "pthread_cond_signal");
}
int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct sigevent sev;
    struct itimerspec ts;
    timer_t *tidlist;
    int s, j;

    if (argc < 2)
        usageErr("%s secs[/nsecs][:int-secs[/int-nsecs]]...\n", argv[0]);

    tidlist = calloc(argc - 1, sizeof(timer_t));
    if (tidlist == NULL)
        errExit("malloc");

    sev.sigev_notify = SIGEV_THREAD;            /* Notify via thread */
    sev.sigev_notify_function = threadFunc;     /* Thread start function */
    sev.sigev_notify_attributes = NULL;
            /* Could be pointer to pthread_attr_t structure */

    /* Create and start one timer for each command-line argument */

    for (j = 0; j < argc - 1; j++) {
        itimerspecFromStr(argv[j + 1], &ts);

        sev.sigev_value.sival_ptr = &tidlist[j];
                /* Passed as argument to threadFunc() */

        if (timer_create(CLOCK_REALTIME, &sev, &tidlist[j]) == -1)
            errExit("timer_create");
        printf("Timer ID: %ld (%s)\n", (long) tidlist[j], argv[j + 1]);

        if (timer_settime(tidlist[j], 0, &ts, NULL) == -1)
            errExit("timer_settime");
    }

    /* The main thread waits on a condition variable that is signaled
       on each invocation of the thread notification function. We
       print a message so that the user can see that this occurred. */

    s = pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);
    if (s != 0)
        errExitEN(s, "pthread_mutex_lock");

    for (;;) {
        s = pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mtx);
        if (s != 0)
            errExitEN(s, "pthread_cond_wait");
        printf("main(): expireCnt = %d\n", expireCnt);
    }
}
```

Taken from [online source code](http://man7.org/tlpi/code/online/dist/timers/ptmr_sigev_thread.c.html).

Also read the Chapter 23 of the book, this code is explained in great detail there.

To test the code above, one would enter

```
$ ./ptmr_sigev_thread 5:5 10:10
```

This will set two timers: one with initial expiry of 5 seconds and an interval with 5 seconds, and the other with 10 respectively.

The definitions for helper functions can be found by following the link on the book's source code above.

Answer (score 3):

Linux has timerfd. https://lwn.net/Articles/251413/. This allows a waitable time to be used together with select/poll/epoll. Alternatively you can use the timeout on select/poll/epoll.